# How to set camelCase to code generated by code templates in Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: flash-builder4.5, code-templates

I'm trying to change the default event handler code generator, so that it generates the name of the function as **onComponentidEventname** For example:

```
<s:Button id="myButton" 
          click="onMyButtonClick(event)" />
```

The code template I use is:

```
${namespace} ${modifiers}function ${:method_name('on${component_id}${event_name}')}(${event}:${event_type}):${return_type}{${cursor}}
```

But the result is **onmyButtonclick** instead of **onMyButtonClick**.

Any ideas if that is possible and how to do that?

Thanks in advance,

*Blaze*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to apply transformations on the code variables...you can submit a feature request if you really need it - go to http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB/component/10660 and click on "Feature Request" (you need to be logged in for that).